# "During period of fermentation" vs. "during the period of fermentation" - can we use the definite article?

Tags: articles

From a [book published by Cambridge University Press](http://assets.cambridge.org/97805215/13364/excerpt/9780521513364_excerpt.pdf):

> In a batch operation, all necessary medium components and the inoculum are added at the beginning and not during **period of fermentation**. Therefore, their concentrations are not controlled but are allowed to vary as the living cells take them up. The products, be they intra- or extracellular, are harvested only at the end of the run. Basic controls for pH, temperature, dissolved oxygen, and foam are applied during the course of batch culture.

Can we use "the" before "period of fermentation"?

This would then refer to "the period of fermentation that you're undertaking (the fermentation you're undertaking)". I'm accustomed to see "the" then there's an "of-phrase" involved. Maybe here it's okay to either use or omit "the"?

Comment: If I had written this book, I would've used _'the'_ too. But I'm not sure if it's required at all instances. Maybe the author didn't want to use to many _'the'_ 's in the sentence? 

*"In a batch operation, all necessary medium components and **the** inoculum are added at **the** beginning and not during (**the**) period of fermentation."*

Comment: The article is needed there before **period**. It might  be dropped before **inoculum**.  Or one could say "...and not during fermentation".  **Period of** is unnecessary because fermentation is a process that takes time.  I would also write "during the course of *the* batch culture" or "during the batch culture".

Comment: Consider *not during the fermentation period.*

Comment: It might just be an editing oops - _"... added at the beginning and not during fermentation."_ might be how it started out, and then someone thought that "fermentation" didn't match "the beginning" as a period of time and tried to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article is needed there before **period**. It might be dropped before **inoculum**. Or one could say "...and not during fermentation". **Period** **of** is unnecessary because fermentation is a process that takes time. I would also write "during the course of the batch culture" or "during the batch culture".

(kudos to TRomano)